# Is there a way to use microsoft online voices (tts) in Ubuntu?

Tags: text-to-speech

Microsoft Edge has that feature called "Read Aloud" that allows you to read web pages or ebooks with very realistic voices available online.
I checked the Linux version of the browser but that feature isn't available on it (yet).
I was wondering if any of you guys had found an app or something that would enable the use of those voices in Ubuntu ?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

you can use that through a python package `pip install edge-tts`. this project is worth exploring [link](https://github.com/rany2/edge-tts).

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft  web voices(Microsoft Edge) to read books stored in my Calibre library in Ubuntu 23.10
my solution was

1. install Microsoft Edge for linux app
2. install&start Calibre ebook  library program
3. on Calibre screen = click <Connect/share> menu button then select "start content server"
4. goto your  Ubuntu computer settings screen and select   settings/default apps change to read as "web = Microsoft Edge"
5. on Calibre screen = click <Connect/share> menu button then
   select "Visit Content server in browser"
6. Microsoft Edge now runs/opens a  Calibre Content server web page where you select a book cover and then select read.
7. right click on books text page and select "Read Aloud".
   top righthand  of page a small speech control window opens with 5 icons
8. in Microsoft Edge settings change home page to the calibre Content server web page.  for example mine is http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or [http://[::1]:8080/](http://%5B::1%5D:8080/)
9. go back your  Ubuntu computer settings screen and changeback  to web = (your original web browser)

Note
using
Microsoft Edge App for Calibre Library books.

to easily use at a later time just start Calibre progam & click <connect/share> menu button then select "start content server" and then you just minimise Calibre program main screen.
select Ubuntu "Show Apps" and select  Microsoft Edge App then
click on Microsoft Edge "homepage" icon and then you are in Calibre content server book page.
Help =  complete Calibre user manual https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/